# Solr indexing Title and Text together

Tags: solr, lucene

I am indexing certain documents in Solr which have a **Title** and **Text**. I dont want to create a separate field called **Title** in the document schema and want to index the **title** by putting it inside the **text** itself in some way so that title words are given more importance while scoring. 
e.g. **Title** : Olympics 2012, **Text** : In December 2012, Olympics were held in......

I want to put the Title words in the Text itself, above should have just one field called Text with Title words inside it. 
e.g. **Text** : Olympics 2012 In December 2012, Olympics were held in......

In the above, title words will not be given any special importance. Is there a way I can accomplish this by giving **title** words a little extra importance than other words in **Text** field while indexing/scoring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> giving title words a little extra importance than other words in Text
>   field while indexing/scoring

I think there is no need to copy the title field to text field to boost the **title** over **text** field. Assuming you have index both fields as full text,  please consider to use [edismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax) query, and provide the [qf (Query Fields)](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#qf_.28Query_Fields.29) as

```
qf=title^10 text
```

which indicates that matches in **title** are 10 times more significant than matches in **text**

The following is an example query in case it helps

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=Olympics&defType=edismax&qf=title^10.0+text
```